# Google CSE bug in result

Tags: google-search, google-search-api, google-custom-search

We are trying to get same google search result via google CSE. 
But its not working like google.

For example if you search for "site:.yt syria", Then you can see there is 8 results for "hry.yt" that in google search, But when you search this string in Google CSE then you can see only 3 results.

another Issue is, On google you can see there is lots of results, with more then 2 page google page, But on CSE there is only two pages.

On Page 2 you can see, Syria.yt is available in google search, But on CSE you cant see syria.yt.

Google search

https://www.google.co.in/#q=site:.yt+syria&start=0

CSE

https://cse.google.com/cse/publicurl?cx=014829541997591622340:tjnrnsryqse

So, Is this a bug in CSE, or we missed some configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Google Custom Search isn't supposed to produce the same results as Google. They are different and independent from each other.